# Model Inheritance Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop

Let's say I have the following classes:

- Animal
- Dog
- Golden Retriever
- Daschund

I want Animal as a base class, Dog is a child class of animal, and the other two to be children classes of Dog.

What's the best practice for implementing this within Laravel? Is it to have four models, and four separate tables? Or would it be better to have two tables, one for animal and one for dog.

Furthermore, if each animal has a 'makeSound' function, I can do so with an interface, and then let's say Dog would woof, but the different dog types might have some override making them do something slightly differently. What I am confused about is, how do I understand what is a Golden Retriever?

If it was just animal, I could do

```
$animals = Animal::get();
```

but I'm unsure how I'd do:

```
$daschunds = Daschund::get();
```

Any advice / reading material on the topic would be highly appreciated. I understand it in terms of OOP, but not within a Laravel environment. I read articles, but nothing Laravel-specfic came up.

Comment: What makes you want to use inheritance here? And what makes you think that would even be a good idea in the first place? Are you familiar with the Object-Relational Impedence Mismatch problem?

Comment: @Dai So the way I'm thinking, if I have a system that has 10 different animal types, and for each of those animal types there's 4+ specific types, then inheritance is the best way to go? So I can call a general animal class, and then call the correct functions depending on what specific animal that instance is. 

I'm assuming from your comment that you disagree and know of a better way / I'm overlooking something? Thanks!

Comment: _"and for each of those animal types there's 4+ specific types, then inheritance is the best way to go"_ - not necessarily: I suggest you read this article first: https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/

Comment: @Dai thank you, will get that read. Appreiciate the time.

Comment: To me, your example makes more sense as something like `Animal 1:1 Type 1:1 Breed`, where `animals.type_id` and `animals.breed_id` would point to `{name: 'Dog'}` and `{name: 'Golden Retriever'}` respectively. You'd have 3 Models, `Animal`, `Type` and `Breed`, and a Relationship between them. Then you'd be able to query for `Dog` records and `Golden Retriever` records separately. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent and https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships for full Documentation. This wouldn't have any inheritance though; it's rare to actually use that in Laravel's Models.

Comment: Hi! From your comments I understand you are willing to change the schema/model, and it seems that you should. But first of all, what exactly are you trying to achieve? We should also separate the two problems: OOP modeling and Database modeling, they serve distinct purposes and can (sometimes) coexist independently.

Comment: You could have three separate tables, except Animal. Make animal as trait, declare some common variables and  "makeSound" in Animal trait class, then use it in your child classes. IT can be used in controller directly, I think should somehow fulfill the purpose. https://www.positronx.io/laravel-traits-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all planned models are animals, you should definitely have an animal table and an Animal model.

Now, if your more specific models have different behavior than Animal in general, then you may inherit models, so their methods will handle things properly. That is, if your differences on PHP only, then you may have models inheriting from each-other with the same table as reference and your app would know by some criteria when and how to operate with the different models.

If you have database differences as well, that is, in the case of Dog you need to have extra information, you may have an attribute table for dogs, having a foreign key to your animal table.

Finally, you may decide to have different tables for each, in which case you would do better by implementing an AbstractAnimal class and have your more specific animal model classes extend it in their own way, so you could implement whatever is common into your AbstractAnimal class.

As for which is better from the above; that's largely dependent on your exact scenario.